# Как ассоциировать программу с определенноми типами через реестр?

Tags: windows, типы, файлы, реестр

Как ассоциировать программу с определенноми типами через реестр?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тоже элементарно. Ассоциации создаются в разделе

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
```

Прямо в корне раздела создаем раздел с именем ".ext" (свое ext, конечно), в нем раздел "shell", в нем раздел "open", а в нем раздел "command". Вот в нем как значение по умолчанию указываем команду для открытия файла, например "C:\myprog %1".

Можно интереснее - рекомендую посмотреть хотя бы

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt
```

и проследить цепочку дальше - txtfile и т.д. А потом другие зарегистрированные расширения посмотреть - там еще интереснее.

Comment: Лучше C:\myprog "%1" чтобы не было проблем с путями с пробелами

Comment: @insolor, справедливо